# Failed to load URL because the scheme does not have a registered handler, using extension URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use window.open to open an extension page, I don't care about checking if the user has the extension, I just want to open a window that starts with `extension://`, it's not working and says failed to load url because the scheme does not have a registered handler. My code looks like this:

```
const openedWindow = window.open("extension://<extension url>", "", "width=300, height=300");

openedWindow.onload = () => {
  openedWindow.close();
}
```

this code works with normal urls, but not with ones starting with `extension://`. Is there any way to open a url like this?

edit: needed to use `chrome-extension://` instead of just extension. Now there's a new problem, chrome is blocking the page. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to open a window with the URL `extension://<extension url>`?

Comment: The extension must expose this page in its `web_accessible_resources`, otherwise it won't open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the correct URL for a chrome extension is `chrome-extension://1234`

Also popups should be explicitly allowed by a user interaction on the popup permission that Chrome asks in the URL bar

Comment: now its saying blocked by chrome. any way around that?

Comment: have you listed the resource in manifest `web_accessible_resources`.